# Django Models - get descendants in table with relationship to self

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Given the the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    belongsTo = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, related_name='parentOf')

    def get_descendants(self):
        "Returns items descendants"
        pass
```

How would I implement the `get_descendants` function to get something similar to the following for `n` descendants:

```
Item.objects.filter(belongs_to=item).filter(belongs_to__belongs_to=item).filter(...)
```

Comment: do you mean getting entire sub tree? or direct descendants only?

Comment: For instance, given the current item (self), return a set consisting of the child and that child's child, and that child's child and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into Django-MPTT : http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/overview.html especially the model methods it has : http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html#mpttmodel-instance-methods

It offers everything you would be needing in order to manipulate such relationship, I've used it in a few projects involving models similar to yours and it is quite simple to use.

If you don't want to use any third party app, then a loop returning a queryset of objects seems to be a way to deal with this.

Comment: With MPTT would I have to go back and rewrite any views that already use the current Item model?

Comment: As far as I understand your question, you haven't yet used any custom method related to the items descendants. Using MPTT would only force you to change the related field (belongsTo -btw it should be belongs_to if you were to follow the Python guidelines-). Thus I can think of no necessary changes in your views, but your database will have to change (be it with South or any other method).